# Neither "import" nor "require" works

Tags: javascript, noty

I'm using Noty version 3 https://github.com/needim/noty. According to the documentation I should use require or import.

```
import Noty from 'noty';

new Noty({
    text: 'Notification text'
}).show();

// or

const Noty = require('noty');

new Noty({
    text: 'Notification text'
}).show();
```

But none works. Even in the last version of Chrome.

When I'm using require:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

And when import:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: are you running it in node?

Comment: Why don't you just include it using a `script` tag?

Comment: require is part of server-side nodeJS. For browser code you need to include libraries via a `<script>` tag. Two different operating environments.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't agree with giving thumbs down to questions. I thought where was no such thing as a stupid question.

That said, you can definitely use `import` or `require`. You're just going to have to use something like Browserify to make them work.

If you really want to get that way, I've got a repo [here](https://github.com/peterbarraud/rapo-browserify-budo-browserifycss-noty) that I just set up to try out Noty stuff